Beanstalkd work queue ECS task shutdown issues
I have beanstalkd running in an ECS cluster. When the beanstalkd process is started in the entry point script, the binlog argument is added to the process for resiliency.
This binlog is stored in a mounted drive.
The issue I am having is that when a new task is started, the old task is still connected to the mount drive so the new one fails. Sometimes the previous task takes around 5 minutes to fully shutdown.
Is there anyway to force the previous task to stop before the new one starts?
Or is there just a better way to do this in general?
